# QGestureRecognizer automatically destroyed by QGestureManager?

Tags: c++, qt, destructor, gesture-recognition

I have recently experienced `exit code 255` in my Qt 5.7 application. This happened right after I added my custom `QGestureRecognizer`. I have debugged into the Qt's sources and I came to the conclusion that the `QGestureManager` automatically disposes of all `QGestureRecognizer` instances. The line that causes the issue is inside the destructor of widget where the recognizer is created and registered:

```
Demo::~Demo() {
  // delete other stuff

  delete recognizer;
}
```

The thing is `QGestureRecognizer` doesn't support (at least according to the documentation and by looking at the constructor's signature) the `parent-child` relationship in Qt since it's not derived from `QObject` (or any subclass of that fundamental Qt class). This means that one cannot assign a `parent` to the its constructor hence `QCustomGestureRecognizer recognizer = new QCustomGestureRecognizer (this)` isn't possible. Continuing this line of thought this means that one has to manually trigger the destructor by calling `delete recognizer`. Or so I thought...

At the end of the life of my application the `QGestureManager` is called. In there there is a list of recognizers called `m_recognizers`. It contains a bunch of the built-in recognizers (such as the one for the `Tap` gesture) along with the registered custom recognizer (in my case it was registered as `257`). The destructor of `QGestureManager` iterates through the list and deletes its entries.

When the `delete recognizer` line is present I get a segmentation fault when `qDeleteAll(...)` (for the `m_recognizers`) reaches the custom recognizer's entry since it attempts to delete something that has already been deleted.

After I commented out the `delete recognizer` line in my widget's destructor I no longer face the issue however I'm still uncertain if I'm not breaking my code somewhere. The exit code is not (as expected) a `0` but the information on how recognizers are disposed is completely missing from the official documentation.

Has anyone encountered this problem? I'm not excluding the possibility that the issue arises from some other part of my code although it seems quite unlikely considering that it appears when the default `QWidget` destructor is called. As per C++ standard when inheriting a class first the subclass' destructor is called (in my case this is the `Demo` custom widget - no issues there) and then the base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
Qt::GestureType QGestureRecognizer::registerRecognizer(QGestureRecognizer *recognizer)
```

the System does take ownership of the object and you should not delete it yourself.

Excerpt from the Documentation:

> The application takes ownership of the recognizer and returns the
>   gesture type ID associated with it.

Comment: Thanks. I figured that much :P Still nice to see that it's actually mentioned in the documentation.